# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ImageSourcePropType'

Tags: typescript, react-native, svg

**Background**
I'm trying to use a SVG component which has the property `xlinkHref` within an `Image` tag. The file was a plain SVG but I turned it into a React Native Component `(TSX)` using https://react-svgr.com/playground/?native=true. I've used very simple SVG icons before with the same method but none had the `xlinkHref` property.

**Problem**

The component at some point has an `Image` tag within it which goes like this:  `xlinkHref="data:image/png;base64,`, however, straight after that it has about 474 lines of encripted information, or at least that is what I believe it is. As an example, this is the first half of the first line: `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAeUAAAJwCAYAAAC3c3kPAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAQABJREFUeAH`. The `xlinkHref`tag is automatically highlighted as incorrect by VS Code and I get the error mentioned in the title:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ImageSourcePropType'.

And below that the error message mentions that:

> The expected type comes from property 'xlinkHref' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<ImageProps, any, any>> & Readonly & Readonly<...>'

I am not much of an expert programmer and can't understand what the error is trying to tell me, so if anyone would be as kind to explain, it'd mean a lot.

**Question**

Is it possible to use SVG components which have this kind of property and assigned value in React Native or is it simply not compatible? How can I go about solving it? Is this a known issue or have I just ran into a new roadblock? I couldn't find anything on the internet regarding this specific issue.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me: `xlinkHref={'...' as any}`

Comment: I can't believe I didn't consider the sheer power of simply typescripting things. Thanks a whole lot.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of TypeScript and should not be done.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there's a more 'TypeScripting' way to do that.

```
/**
 * @see https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#source
 */
export type ImageSourcePropType = ImageURISource | ImageURISource[] | ImageRequireSource;
```

```
/*
 * @see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/ImageSourcePropType.js
 */
export interface ImageURISource {
    /**
     * `uri` is a string representing the resource identifier for the image, which
     * could be an http address, a local file path, or the name of a static image
     * resource (which should be wrapped in the `require('./path/to/image.png')`
     * function).
     */
    uri?: string | undefined;
    /**
```

As we can see, `ImageSourcePropType` inherits type `ImageURISource`, which declares a member called `uri`, so an plain object with `uri` property will do the job.

so:

```
<Image style={...somestyle} source={{ uri: ...the_path_to_your_image }}/>
```